# How to get current time in AM/PM format in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query I am using =>

```
replace(substring(CONVERT(varchar,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30'),100),13,LEN(CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),100))), ' +05:30','')
```

output I am getting => `5:40PM`

but I want output => `5:40 PM`

So how can I get this output

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stuff()` to add a space before AM/PM. You can also remove the `replace()` by setting the `substring()` length to `8`.

```
select stuff(substring(convert(varchar(30),switchoffset(sysdatetimeoffset(), '+05:30'),100),13,8),6,0,' ')
```

If you want to remove the leading space, you can wrap the above in `ltrim()`.

---

You could also use two `replace()` along with converting to `time` and style `100`.

```
select replace(replace(convert(varchar(8),convert(time,switchoffset(sysdatetimeoffset(), '+05:30')),100),'AM',' AM'),'PM',' PM')
```

---

In sql server 2012+ you can use [**`format()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
select format(switchoffset(sysdatetimeoffset(), '+05:30'),'h:mm tt')
```

But `format()` can be slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NITZM59410

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert with 100 as below

```
select CONVERT(varchar(8),CAST(getdate() AS TIME),100)
```

Comment: Sir it gives output => 12:16PM but I want in 12 hour format time and which contain space bewtween time and AM/PM (like 09:00 AM)

Comment: I think 12:16 has to be 12:16pm rite? in for 1pm it has to go with 1 instead of 13 correct? Am I missing something here?